# non utility static methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a method which extract the loggedin user details from springsecuritycontext object.

I have read that only utility methods(which does certain calculation) should be static .

Here is my method , it doesn't seems to be a utility method but I don't find any reason why I shouldn't make it static as I am using it in multiple beans

```
public static int getSignedUpUser()
    {
        final SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

        if(ctx != null)
        {
            final Authentication auth = ctx.getAuthentication();

            if(auth != null)
            {
                final Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();


                if(principal instanceof AUser)
                {
                    final AUser au = (AUser)principal;
                    return au.getId();
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the question exactly?

Comment: Your question is if it should be static?

Comment: I have made the method static , is it correct or I should make it non-static

Comment: @Programmer well its hard question to answer. since I don't know how the rest of your program look like, but as long as it doesn't effect other threads/methods data then it should be ok

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` is no utility method, and it is static. There are exceptions to this "rule". I see nothing bad with a static method here, especially since it in turn relies on a static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short: use static method is OK.

When we say static methods should be a utility method, we are talking about that a static method should be thread-safe.

Let's see the SecurityContextHelper.getContext() method. It is implemented like this:

```
private static SecurityContextHolderStrategy strategy;

public static SecurityContext getContext() {
    return strategy.getContext();
}
```

Notice that it returns context from a static variable `strategy`. So the `strategy` must keep thread-safe.

`SecurityContextHolderStrategy` interface have three implementations:

[image]

two of them are thread local, the other one has a `private static SecurityContext contextHolder;`

Then let's see SecurityContextHolder.initialize() method:

```
private static void initialize() {
    if ((strategyName == null) || "".equals(strategyName)) {
        // Set default
        strategyName = MODE_THREADLOCAL;
    }

    if (strategyName.equals(MODE_THREADLOCAL)) {
        strategy = new ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy();
    } else if (strategyName.equals(MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)) {
        strategy = new InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy();
    } else if (strategyName.equals(MODE_GLOBAL)) {
        strategy = new GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy();
    } else {
        // Try to load a custom strategy
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(strategyName);
            Constructor<?> customStrategy = clazz.getConstructor();
            strategy = (SecurityContextHolderStrategy) customStrategy.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(ex);
        }
    }

    initializeCount++;
}
```

This shows that MODE_THREADLOCAL is the default strategy. And even GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy uses a static context holder too. So you can use them in static method.

Answer (score 0):

conceptually the method impl shown is a part of instance of a class. that's why manipulations can be static. so i prefer to use the instane rather tahn static methhod.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking the question the right way. If you look at the method of `getSignedUpUser`, you see the class it is part of. Your question should be this:

> Who gets the signed up user? An instance, or all the instances
>   collectively (the class)?

`static` members or methods are collective members or methods. For example, the number of birds is a collective data about birds, it is `static`. Non-static members or methods are individual. For example, a bird has a weight, which is associated individually to the bird.